# ASP.NET Configuration icon in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net

Я столкнулся с проблемой отсутствия в Visual Studio 2013 ASP.NET конфигурации (инструмент администрирования веб-сайтов). После поисков в интернете, решение было: [Использование Membership API](http://smartdotnet.ru/ispolzovanie-membership-api.html).

Теперь возникла другая проблема. Когда я захожу на страницу, в моем примере это `http://localhost:8080/asp.netwebadminfiles/default.aspx?applicationPhysicalPath=D:\project\aaa\_0067&applicationUrl=/`,
требуется ввести пароль и логин, а в описании этой проблемы (там даже есть видео), такой проблемы нет. Если кто-то сталкивался с этим, подскажите.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Утилита для настройки membership требует ntlm аутентификации. Нужно просто ввести имя и пароль текущего пользователя.

IE отсылает их сам (в виде токена). FF - нет, он не доверяет localhost. Но его можно научить:

1. открыть about:config.
2. отфильтровать настройки по "ntlm".
3. дабл-кликнуть "network.automatic-ntlm-auth.trusted-uris", вписать "localhost" и сохранить.